# Attach link to a button in Django

Tags: python, django

The following Django template code for opening a different page template works fine:

```
<p>
    <a id="selenium" href="{% url 'javascript:results' %}">Selenium</a>
</p>
```

However, I want the link to open upon button click, but the followng code does not work:

```
<button>
    <a id="selenium" href="{% url 'javascript:results' %}">Selenium</a>
</button>
```

How do I attach a link to a button in Django then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: Try this `<button onclick="location.href='{% url 'javascript:results' %}'" type="button">bla bla</button>`.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner -- in my dev environment (Visual Studio Code, v1.81.1) that gets flagged as a JS syntax error.  It gets confused because you have single quotes nested inside single quotes.  Also, you're missing the closing semicolon between the closing single & double quote.  Also, the `type="button"` is redundant, this is a `<button>` element to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is HTML problem which you can solve in many ways. One such way is below.

```
<form>
    <button formaction="{% url 'javascript:results' %}">Selenium</button>
</form>
```